# Java 7 to Java 8 issue with setting background color of TextArea and StyleSheets/css

Tags: java, css, fxml, java-8

I had a Java FXML application functioning in Java 7u51 that I built in NetBeans 7.4.
I have installed Java 8 and NetBeans 8. 
I recreated my little application in Java 8/NetBeans 8.  Everything is working except some of the css styling. Specifically, I have a Text Area.

Here is the Text Area FXML:

```
<TextArea layoutX="1" layoutY="230" minHeight="120" minWidth="320" editable="false" fx:id="eventWindow" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0"/>
```

Here is the corresponding css styling:

```
#eventWindow {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}
```

When I run the application, the background of my text area stays white! What's frustrating is that other things from my css file are behaving as they should.  I have already tried the following:

1) I tried putting this in my css:

```
.events {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-text-fill: white;  
}
```

...and adding 'styleclass="events"' into my FXML.

2) and I tried:

```
.textarea {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-text-fill: white;  
}
```

no dice on either of those.

I have also double-checked to make sure that nothing could be overriding it. And... it's working just fine in Java 7u51.

I know this is not the most critical thing on the planet... but it's driving me nuts!

Thanks in advance!
-Adeena

Comment: I also tried .text-area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the TextArea consist of several nodes (TextArea,ScrollPane,Content). To change the background of the content node the following css can be used:

```
.text-area .scroll-pane .content{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

The substructure of nodes is explained in the JavaFX css documentation: http://download.java.net/jdk8/jfxdocs/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#textarea

Here's a link to a related issue: https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-31904

Comment: Thanks! That seems to then be a change in Java 8?  A requirement that the sub-nodes are used... Either way, this is working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

in the fxml `styleClass="eventWindow"`

and then in the css

`.eventWindow {
    -fx-background-color: black;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}`

works for me

Comment: That, and all the other options I tried, work just fine in Java 7. They are not working in Java 8. (I tried the exact example you provided)

Comment: I'm using 8-b127.  I didn't use it with a text field nor did I use the same name as the fx:id, but I doubt those are the problem.

Comment: I just tried using #eventWindow as in your example and it does not work.  Only using a .eventWindow seems to work.

Comment: I've fiddled with it more and I'm convinced I've found a bug. I'm reporting it here: http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/